# Making static library for Android Native app (NDK)

Tags: android-ndk, static-libraries

Situation:

- Eclipse with Android SDK and SDK
- I am studying and wants to develop arm and Android version of our current library (which uses no platform-specific API)

Question:

- How can I make a C++ static library (.a) for arm CPU? I cannot find any good documentation explaining it.
- Assuming that C++ static library use no Android specific API, can it be used by Android Native application? If NO, what is needed for making a static library for Android Native apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[2] Yes, it's OK to use a static library in Android Native app even if the C++ code does use Android specific APIs.

[1] You must install [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and run `ndk-build` command for your project. The NDK includes documentation and samples that will guide you to prepare the **Makefile** (by convention, it is called `Android.mk`).

Minimal `Android.mk` will probably look like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_MODULE := imays
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := imays.cpp
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```